# Disable specific months in every year datetimepicker

Tags: jquery

I have a month year datetimepicker  in this i want to disable all months in every year except jan ,june
below code i tried but not working beforeshowmonth is not working

```
$('.newcqi').datetimepicker({

                viewMode: 'years',
                format: 'MM/YYYY',
                beforeShowMonth: function (date) {
                    var month = date.getMonth() + 1; // +1 because JS months start at 0
                   // var day = date.getDate();
                    return [!(month == 2 && month == 3 && month == 4 &&  month == 5 ), ""];
                }
                

            });
```

Comment: That isn't a jQuery builtin feature. Please edit the question and explain what library you're asking about. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using jQuery UI library for date picker [jQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Your question is little confusing for me but as I understand from code you want to **Enable** Jan, Feb, March, April May & June. and **Disable** Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov & Dec from every year.

So code will be like

```
$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        if(date.getMonth() === 0 || date.getMonth() === 1 || date.getMonth() === 2 || date.getMonth() === 3 || date.getMonth() === 4 || date.getMonth() === 5){
            return [true];
        }
        return [false]
    }
});
```

jsFiddle demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shwgk09v/)

Comment: but the above code is not working for me as i am using bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js.

Comment: for bootstrap datetimepicker Im not sure but you can use jQueryUI datepicker which is very simple and easy to use, also you will get lots of support on internet.

Answer (score 0):

This below code worked for me  for datetimepicker i am posting the code so  that will help for others...

```
  $('.ddmmyyyyDate2newcqi').datetimepicker({


            viewMode: 'years',
            format: 'MM/YYYY',
            useCurrent: false
           });

    


      $(document).ready(function () {
            
    var event = document.getElementById("starttime_cqinew");
                event.addEventListener("mouseover", monthdisablestartime());

});
     function monthdisablestartime() {
                
                 var mS = ['Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
                    for (var i = 0, length = mS.length; i < length; i++) {
    
                        $('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td > span:contains(' + mS[i] + ')').addClass('disabled').css("background-color", "lightgrey");
    
                    }
    
              
            }
```